# convert column to varchar in oracle which is mysql longtext

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, varchar, dblink

i have a insert statement pulling data from db link.

```
insert into table (a,b,c)
    select a,b,c from table@mysqldb;
```

here column c is long type in mysql and in oracle its varchar

i tried to cast as  varchar, substr(c, 1,2400), UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2,dbms_lob.substr
 none of them are working on oracle side.

tried cast on mysql read part no use.

Can someone tell me how to do this. Here Iam trying to convert long to varchar. we cannot load as clob as this table is used in many places and we cannot change things at so many places

Thanks.

Comment: What error do you get? (I'm guessing that the command is executed within Oracle, right?)

Comment: Yes iam running it on oracle , when tried with substr
ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Comment: What do you get if you execute `select a,b,c from table@mysqldb;`?

Comment: well this is run inside a proc, we cannot directly query the mysql db we dont have access to it.

Comment: I was thinking about running the query from within Oracle (e.g. using SQL-Developer or the like), not MySQL.

Comment: yes i was trying to run through sql develoer it throws error"connection description for remote database not found", my user doesn't have access to run

Comment: Your SQL-Developer will not be able to access a connection unless you OPEN it. (_New Connection_).

Comment: I dont have any details about source system its not in our visibility

Answer (score 0):

i had to convert the target column to clob to handle this scenario